# TinyMCE focus in and focus out loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I have a problem with TinyMCE 4.x and its behavior. Whenever I initialize TinyMCE on popup i get focus in and focus out loop and its looks like flickering.

Here is a gif that shows exactly what is happening. You can see that on main page where i initialize TinyMCE everything is fine and its working as expected, but on popup its kinda start focusing in and out. You can see it in developer tool as well, that class for it changes from `mce-content-body` to `mce-content-body mce-edit-focus` and then back.

[image]

Here is code how I initialize the TinyMCE.:

```
initializeTinyMCE(element){
    var self = this;
    if (element == 'p') {
        var toolbar = 'forecolor | fontsizeselect fontselect | align | bold italic underline | bullist numlist | link | strokes | done';
    } else if (element == 'h') {
        var toolbar = 'forecolor | fontsizeselect | fontselect | H | align | bold italic underline | link | strokes | done';
    }

    if(self.el.parent().hasClass('popup_content')){
        var inline = false
    } else {
        var inline = true
    }
    tinyMCE.init({
        selector: `#${self.el.find('.content_element').attr('id')}`,
        auto_focus: self.testFocus(self.el.find('.content_element').attr('id')),
        content_css : 'assets/tinymce/custom/fonts.css',
        inline: true,
        menubar: false,
        theme: 'modern',
        skin: 'pagesource',
        plugins: ['lists link textcolor colorpicker strokes'],
        toolbar: toolbar,
        fontsize_formats: '8px 10px 12px 14px 18px 24px 36px 48px',
        setup: function (editor) {
            self.clonedEl = self.el.clone()
            editor.addButton('align', {
                type: 'menubutton',
                text: '',
                icon: 'alignleft',
                menu: [{
                    text: '',
                    icon: 'alignleft',
                    onclick: function () {
                        editor.execCommand('JustifyLeft');
                    }
                }, {
                    text: '',
                    icon: 'aligncenter',
                    onclick: function () {
                        editor.execCommand('JustifyCenter');
                    }
                }, {
                    text: '',
                    icon: 'alignright',
                    onclick: function () {
                        editor.execCommand('JustifyRight');
                    }
                }, {
                    text: '',
                    icon: 'alignjustify',
                    onclick: function () {
                        editor.execCommand('JustifyFull');
                    }
                }]
            }),
            editor.addButton('H', {
                type: 'menubutton',
                text: 'H',
                icon: false,
                menu: [{
                    text: 'H1',
                    onclick: function() {
                        editor.execCommand('FormatBlock', false, 'h1');
                    }
                }, {
                    text: 'H2',
                    onclick: function() {
                        editor.execCommand('FormatBlock', false, 'h2');
                    }
                }, {
                    text: 'H3',
                    onclick: function() {
                        editor.execCommand('FormatBlock', false, 'h3');
                    }
                }, {
                    text: 'H4',
                    onclick: function() {
                        editor.execCommand('FormatBlock', false, 'h4');
                    }
                }, {
                    text: 'H5',
                    onclick: function() {
                        editor.execCommand('FormatBlock', false, 'h5');
                    }
                }, {
                    text: 'H6',
                    onclick: function() {
                        editor.execCommand('FormatBlock', false, 'h6');
                    }
                }]
            });
            editor.addButton('done', {
                text: 'Done',
                icon: false,
                onclick: function () {
                    tinyMCE.remove();
                    self.openEditManager();
                    self.el.find('.ui-resizable-handle').removeClass('hidden');
                }
            });
            editor.on('remove', function(ed) {
                self.removeTinyMCE(ed);
                window.historyMem.addRecord(self.clonedEl, self.el.clone())
            });
        },
        init_instance_callback: function (editor) {
            editor.on('focus', function (e) {
                 console.log(2)
            });
        }
    });
}
```

And this is the element and structure on which the problem persists:

```
<div class="body_wrapper">
  <div class="project_wrapper" data-uuid="<%= @page.uuid %>">
    <div class="edit_grid">
      <div class="popup_editor">
        <div class="popup">
          <div class="popup_content">
            <div class='widget'>
              <div class='tinymce_editor'> # this is the element

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note**: When not doing inline editor it works fine.

I don't need exact solution, any suggestions and ideas would be appreciated. I have tried almost everything, like moving editor popup in different position in DOM, stripping all of the settings, etc. Thank you.